# Splash Screen to API 33 kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

I don´t know how to do a splash screen right now. I saw some tutorials of the api to do a splah screen and my activity crush always to add the theme. The app crush after run the splash screen correctly. This code its my theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.BookTFGNormal.MySplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" tools:targetApi="s">@drawable/icon_book</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreen </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I add the theme at my MainActivity since AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BookTFGNormal.MySplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And I  add this code at MainActivity:

```
 installSplashScreen()
```

At the tutorials; they add:

```
setContent{}
```

but I receive an error at setContent{} and I added to gradle implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of defining repositories in Gradle. Recently, projects created in the Android Studio wizard no longer include an `allProjects` block in `build.gradle`. They configure the dependency repositories in a `dependencyResolutionManagement` block in the `settings.gradle` file. For example:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS` even fails the build with an error if you attempt to put a `repositories` block in any of your build.gradle files.

Comment: @zapl, yes, I guess that's their way of trying to enforce editing it from only one place. I don't know if their decision-making process for the wizard's default setup is documented publicly anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know that allProjects block in build.gradle. Now all works correctly